# How to make a cron job to save from PHP Smarty Index.tpl to Index.html?

Tags: php, cron, smarty

I want to save some server resources and create a static index.html file from a Smarty template index.tpl that is updated every day.

What is the best way to make a cron job to achieve that?

Comment: Render the template? Smarty has build-in caching abilities btw...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Oh really? I am new to this. Is it automatic or I need to make something?

Comment: Consider the Smarty documentation for the version you're using.. you'd need to configure it properly, but that shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: I was also thinking about the Smarty cache, but I always thought it was regarding the convertion of the Smarty syntax into PHP executable files that replace the template itself. All the variables generated and inserted inside the template may take some computation time (SQL queries, calculation, etc) and if so then the cron task seems to be a good way to reduce load if you know it only needs an update every day. A static HTML file will always be faster than booting-up PHP, Smarty, etc. Static files are also more secure. You can also set HTTP caching headers and use *Varnish* to reduce load.

Comment: @idm: did my answer below help you?

Comment: @PatrickJanser Thanks for it. I got stuck in another issue. Will test it this weekend and mark it accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends if you can run php in command line (CLI) or not on the server. You may need to find the path to the `php` executable as it may not be set in the `PATH`.

If yes then I would just run a home-made script with `php update-index.php` that does the job of regenerating your `index.html` file.

If you cannot run PHP in CLI then you could put this script on your website and call it with `curl` or `wget`. You could protect it with an Apache rule or by just checking the presence of a POST parameter, like this:

```php
<?php

define('API_KEY', '732hCwhjK');

// If the key is missing then just stop execution.
if (!isset($_POST['key']) || $_POST['key'] !== API_KEY) {
  die();
}

// TODO: update your index.html file with Smarty.
// Don't print anything so that the cron doesn't send any mail.
// If you get an error then print it here.
// Cron will then send you the mail with the content printed out.
```

Example of a cron configuration file:

```
MAILTO="your.mail@example.com"

# CRON TASKS SYNTAX
# -----------------
#
# Output dumper: >/dev/null 2>&1
#
# Multiple values with commas: 5,25,45
#
# Every X intervals: */10 * * * * for every 10 minutes
#
# Aliases: @reboot  = run once at startup
#          @hourly  = 0 * * * *
#          @daily   = 0 0 * * *
#          @weekly  = 0 0 * * 0
#          @monthly = 0 0 1 * *
#          @yearly  = 0 0 1 1 *

# Execute update-index.php twice a day, at 6am and 6pm:
0 6,18 * * * /bin/php /home/user/www-data/site/update-index.php 2>&1

# Execute update-index.php via calling the URL at 3am.
# Key is sent via POST to avoid having it visible in the log files.
0 3 * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 --post-data="key=732hCwhjK" "https://your-site.com/update-index.php"
```

### Edit cron tabs

`crontab -e -u username`
If you want to define the editor (nano or vim), prefix with `EDITOR=xxxx` like this:

`EDITOR=vim crontab -e`

User crontab files are here:

`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`

Crontab files can also be stored under:

```
/etc/cron.d/
/etc/cron.hourly/
/etc/cron.daily/
/etc/cron.weekly/
/etc/cron.monthly/
```

They are run at these hours:

`grep run-parts /etc/crontab`

Or just check all the content:

`less /etc/crontab`